# Windows 10 Makefile Setting Variable Issue

Tags: windows, variables, unix, makefile

I'm trying to get the below make file to work in both Windows and Unix. I'm running into trouble where the standard `<VAR> := <Value>` doesn't seem to work correctly in Windows (I installed `make` via the Cholocalety way with `choco install make`). I could check the `ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)` every time but would rather pass around an internal variable. Any help would be appreciated as I can't figure out how to actually google this...

The code output is:

```
Windows_NT
detected_OS: Windows
------------
Not-Windows
```

Code Below:

```
#.RECIPEPREFIX:=> # This doesn't work either...

.PHONY: test

test:


    ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)     # is Windows_NT on XP, 2000, 7, Vista, 10...
        $(eval DET_OS=Windows)
#       DET_OS : =Windows
#       DET_OS=Windows
    else
        $(eval detected_OS = nonWindows)
    endif

    @echo $(OS)
    @echo detected_OS: $(DET_OS)
    @echo ------------
#    ifeq ($(DET_OS), Windows)
    ifeq "$(DET_OS)" "Windows"
        @echo Windows
    else
        @echo Not-Windows
```

Edited: 
It was pointed out that part of the post is missing so I'm adding it here for clarity.  The code should execute the `ifeq ($(DET_OS), Windows)` path in the later part of the code. The output shows it going down the `non-windows` path instead. I was not sure what I needed to do make it go down the `Windows` path with user defined variables

Comment: Please explain the problem you have, when asking questions.  Above you've only said "it doesn't seem to work correctly" which is not useful in diagnosing a problem.  Please show (through cut and paste) the result you got which is incorrect, and explain what about it you consider incorrect and what the correct output you want is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is that you cannot set `make` variables within the recipe. When set within the recipe, it is considered a command to run, not a variable setting. Other than that it works pretty well to me:

```
> Get-Content Makefile
.PHONY: test

ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
  DET_OS := Windows
else
  DET_OS := nonWindows
endif

test:
        @echo $(OS)
        @echo detected_OS: $(DET_OS)
        @echo ------------
ifeq ($(DET_OS),Windows)
        @echo Windows
else
        @echo Not-Windows
endif
```

Output:

```
> ..\make-4.3\WinRel\gnumake.exe
Windows_NT
detected_OS: Windows
------------
Windows

> ..\make-4.3\WinRel\gnumake.exe --version
GNU Make 4.3
Built for Windows32
```

Comment: Thanks raspy! I was not aware for make files. This is actually the first one I have ever made.